# Keep Plank unhidden and maximize windows to plank like in OS X?

Tags: plank, window-management

Plank can be set unhidden by setting `~/.config/plank/dock/settings` -> `HideMode=X` -> `HideMode=0`, but how to set the maximize action to the upper edge of plank like in OS X?

**Screenshot of my plank:**
[image]

**Screenshot of OS X:**
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You achieve that result by setting  the "Never hide" option in System settings > Desktop > Dock.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do this configuration for non eOS/Pantheon?

Answer (score 2):

Go to System Settings -> Desktop -> Dock

[image: Dock Setting]

Comment: Is this answer for a previous version of elementary OS?

Comment: No, its for elementary Freya 0.3.1,  [here my eOS](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JOm8b.png)

Comment: This is interesting. I am assuming there have been several tweaks to that switchboard plugin of late as mine does look slightly different now. Are you fully up to date @mr.ck? I feel the answer is still valid though as 'focused window is maximised' is probably more in line with what the OP asked for.